# Calling a persistent package variable

Tags: sql, database, oracle, package

Ive created a package and a package body that run but I'm unsure of how i can test the value held in my persistent package variable.

Here is the package code, its fairly simple just a delete procedure and create function which are in the package body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE customers AS
FUNCTION create_customer (Country VARCHAR2, First_Name VARCHAR2, Last_name VARCHAR2,
                    Birth_date VARCHAR2, Customer_Type VARCHAR2, Address VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2);
FUNCTION count_customer RETURN NUMBER;
END customers;
```

And now here is the package body

```
create or replace package body customers AS
total_customers NUMBER;
FUNCTION CREATE_CUSTOMER(        
       Country IN VARCHAR2 ,First_Name IN VARCHAR2 ,Last_Name IN VARCHAR2 ,Birth_Date IN VARCHAR2 ,Customer_Type IN VARCHAR2 ,Address IN VARCHAR2
) return VARCHAR2 IS
  new_customer_id VARCHAR2(8);
BEGIN
SELECT custid_seq.NEXTVAL
INTO new_customer_id
FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO customer (Customer_id, Country, First_Name, Last_name, Birth_date, Customer_Type, Address)
VALUES (new_customer_id, Country, First_Name, Last_name, Birth_date, Customer_Type, Address);
total_customers := total_customers + 1;
RETURN (new_customer_id);
end;
PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
total_customers := total_customers - 1;
END;
BEGIN
select count(*) into total_customers from customer;
END;
```

The total_customers is my persistent package variable and only local to this package I just want to know how i can test to see the value currently held in the variable.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried adding a public function that returns the current value? (I think I suggested that on a previous question of yours).

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure of how that would work sorry, I'm extremely knew to PLSQL

Comment: As Alex mentions in passing, the value of `total_customers` is only valid from one session. Because a PL/SQL app on an Oracle database is almost certainly multi-user I would turn it into a function that returns the `count` of the total number of customers.

Comment: A PL/SQL idiom suggestion: you can specify the value of the customer_id to be inserted as `sequence.nextval` and use `returning customer_id into new_customer_id` to get it's value *from the insert statement*. See http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html#inrc for an example that's almost exactly the same as your case.

Comment: One more suggestion (since you mention you're learning PL/SQL): `return` is a statement, not a procedure, so its argument doesn't need brackets: `return new_customer_id;` is perfectly fine.

Comment: And a relational database suggestion: name your tables in plural (since they'll usually contain more than one of each *thing*) and your PL/SQL code packages in singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package specification add:

```
function get_total_customers return number;
```

In your package body add:

```
function get_total_customers return number is
begin
    return total_customers;
end get_total_customers;
```

Then from SQL you can `select customers.get_total_customers from dual`.

The alternative is to have the package variable defined in the specification rather than the body, but then it could be changed externally as well as read.

Either way, the value will only be meaningful [within a session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#CJADDABG); if you set it in one session then that won't be visible in another session. Both can calculate it, but then if you call `create_customer()` in one session, the other will still report the old total.

Comment: hmm I've tried adding that to the code I've already got but for some reason its not liking it and producing an error around then 'end'

Comment: @RichardC - yes, `package` was a placeholder for the real package name, so `select customers.get_total_customers from dual`. Without the `()` probably.

Answer (score 0):

Put your variable to package spec, test it. Then put it back into the body or leave it in the spec. Keep it simple...

Comment: Variables can't be referenced from SQL, only functions can.

Comment: @Colin - not true: Package_name.Variable_name - this is how you'd reference it. Besides, moving variable to the spec will not prevent it from using with function.

Comment: `SELECT package_name.variable_name FROM DUAL;` won't work, you need to create a function which returns it -- if you want to test from SQL, which is what my point was.

Comment: @Colin-this was my assumption, of course. I simply suggested putting variable into the spec instead of body for testing.